# Putting multiple ContentViews in a ScrollView

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm making an app with Xamarin.Forms, and I'm trying to make scrolling menu. How would I do this using a ScrollView and multiple ContentViews or Frames? I've actually already succeeded at doing this, but I need to be able to do it using XAML instead. So, how do I do that?

Comment: Just embed your different content elements in a panel that accepts children like that, like a StackPanel or an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate etc.

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` should have only one child, so you have to use a layout like `Grid` or `StackPanel` etc.

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
     <ContentView>
         <!--put your content here -->
     </ContentView>

     <Frame>
         <!--put your content here -->
     </Frame>

     <ContentView>
         <!--put your content here -->
     </ContentView>
   </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```